# Join to additional table without aggregates summing the duplicated values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following Code.

```
Select  t.Salesperson_Invoiced,        
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) MTD_REV,
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) MTD_GM,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) YTD_REV,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) YTD_GM
From    Sales_History t
Where   t.PG1    = 'Lighting' 
And     t.Office = 'AU' 
And     t.Year   = Year(getdate())
Group By t.Salesperson_Invoiced
```

is it possible for me to add the following

```
SELECT Salesperson_1,sum(Value_Func) as BO_AUD
FROM Datawarehouse.dbo.Open_Orders
where Office = 'AU' and PG1 = 'Lighting'
group by Salesperson_1
```

Salesperson_1 and Salesperson_Invoiced is the joinable field :)

so I can have it look like this ?

| Salesperson_Invoiced | NetNet_Revenue_Func MTD | NetNet_Revenue_Func YTD | GM_Func_Net MTD | GM_Func_Net YTD | BO_AUD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 500 | 100 |  |  |  |
| John | 600 | 200 |  |  |  |
| Peter | 700 | 300 |  |  |  |
| Harry | 800 | 400 |  |  |  |
| Potter | 900 | 1 |  |  |  |

Every time I try and join the tables the data goes crazy and is very wrong !

Apricate your help!

---

Here is an example outputted data I get :

Table One:

| Salesperson_Invoiced | NetNet_Revenue_Func MTD | NetNet_Revenue_Func YTD | GM_Func_Net MTD | GM_Func_Net YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 500 | 1000 | 250 | 500 |
| Harry | 600 | 1200 | 300 | 600 |
| Potter | 700 | 1400 | 350 | 700 |

Table 2

| Salesperson_Invoiced | BO_AUD |
| --- | --- |
| James | 500000 |
| Harry | 600000 |
| Potter | 700000 |

This is what i am trying to achieve :

| Salesperson_Invoiced | NetNet_Revenue_Func MTD | NetNet_Revenue_Func YTD | GM_Func_Net MTD | GM_Func_Net YTD | BO_AUD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 500 | 1000 | 250 | 500 | 500000 |
| Harry | 600 | 1200 | 300 | 600 | 600000 |
| Potter | 700 | 1400 | 350 | 700 | 700000 |

The code i was trying to use was

```
Select distinct  t.Salesperson_Invoiced,        
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) MTD_REV,
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) MTD_GM,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) YTD_REV,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) YTD_GM,
        sum(Value_Func) as BO_AUD
From    Sales_History t
inner join Open_Orders on
t.Salesperson_Invoiced = Open_Orders.Salesperson_1
Where   t.PG1    = 'Lighting' 
And     t.Office = 'AU' 
And     t.Year   = Year(getdate())
Group By t.Salesperson_Invoiced,Salesperson_1
```

But when I try and use that
A) Real data from one of the MTD goes from 6586.00 to 111962.00
B) BO_AUD for the same person blow out to 10907652.210 where it should be 119374.310

Comment: "the data goes crazy and is very wrong".  Please provide *specific* details on the error

Comment: Please supply sample data and concise explanation of what you need.

Comment: hello Both,

I have added more to my question hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Presumably, a salesperson can have many sales in the history table. Likewise, they can have many open orders. So you have a many to many relationship, and your rows multiplicate in the join. To remedy this, do the grouping in a subquery.

Comment: @HoneyBadger is right, you can't just use `GROUP BY` over the whole set, remove the group clause to review all the rows that it is operating over. Sub-query, Cross Apply and or window functions may assist you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate *before* joining:

```
select sh.*, oo.*
from (Select sh.Salesperson_Invoiced,        
              Sum(Case When month(sh.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then sh.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) MTD_REV,
              Sum(Case When month(sh.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then sh.GM_Func_Net End) MTD_GM,
              SUM (Case When sh.Year = Year(getdate()) Then sh.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) YTD_REV,
              SUM (Case When sh.Year = Year(getdate()) Then sh.GM_Func_Net End) YTD_GM
      From Sales_History sh
      Where sh.PG1    = 'Lighting' AND
            sh.Office = 'AU' AND
            sh.Year   = Year(getdate())
      Group By sh.Salesperson_Invoiced
     ) sh left join
     (SELECT Salesperson_1, sum(Value_Func) as BO_AUD
      FROM Datawarehouse.dbo.Open_Orders
      where Office = 'AU' and PG1 = 'Lighting'
      group by Salesperson_1
     ) oo
     on sh.Salesperson_Invoiced = oo.Salesperson_1
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, this does exactly what I need !! Thankyou so much !

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like a case for an `APPLY`, although it can also be done as a join on a CTE/derived table.**

```sql
Select  t.Salesperson_Invoiced,        
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) MTD_REV,
        Sum(Case When month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) MTD_GM,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.NetNet_Revenue_Func End) YTD_REV,
        SUM (Case When t.Year = Year(getdate()) Then t.GM_Func_Net End) YTD_GM,
        o.BO_AUD
From    Sales_History t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(o.Value_Func) as BO_AUD
    FROM Open_Orders o
    WHERE t.Salesperson_Invoiced = o.Salesperson_1
) o
Where   t.PG1    = 'Lighting' 
And     t.Office = 'AU' 
And     t.Year   = Year(getdate())
Group By t.Salesperson_Invoiced, o.BO_AUD;
```

**Notes:**

- The result of the `APPLY` goes into the `GROUP BY` as it is already grouped up against each `Salesperson_Invoiced`
- I suggest you find a better method of filtering by date. In order to use an index, you can't have a function on the column. So instead of `month(t.TranDate) = Month(getdate())...` use `t.TranDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND t.TranDate < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()) + 1, 1)`

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the solution but it still seems to be resulting in incorrect data :(